# My computer freezes during installation

Tags: installation

I have used a 64bit AMD processor with Ubuntu for the last 2 years and have installed 10.04 and then 11.10.

I have tried to upgrade to 12.04 but after the installation starts it keeps asking who I am and it wants me to fill in my name and my computer name, but then the installation freezes.

I have tried the earlier version (9.10), but the same problem persists.

Answer (score -2):

had the same issue... press ctrl+c once and the network configuration dialog will restart... it didn't hang the second time